# Issue accessing Azure Files - File not Found error from Pod logs

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have below configuration in place for accessing Azure Files from my application deployment:

```
volumeMounts:
      - name: lhapidatasource
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
```

My deployment is successfully  running, but when i look at my application logs which tries to access files from my azure file location, it says " File not Found "

/mnt/azure/openapidevshare/datasources/location.csv not found.

My Azure file is configured properly and i have above file present in the azure file location when i look into it from azure portal.

So please help me in identifying the issue. Also i would like to know if there is a way to check pod contents like what is present in it for example what is actually present in "/mnt/azure" as per my volume mount config.

Comment: `kubectl exec -it podname /bin/bash`?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. And i was able to figure out the directory structure as well. We need to give it as /mnt/azure/datasources/location.csv. Where i have removed the main file share name "openapidevshare" as per my post (/mnt/azure/openapidevshare/datasources/location.csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to how paths are constructed in the container.

```
kubectl exec -it podname /bin/bash
```

this command allowed the asker to inspect paths manually and adjust those